# Azure Point-to-Site VPN Resource Manager powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-vpn

I found the link, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-rm-ps/, which give details instructions on how to create a Point-to-Site VPN connection using powershell in the new Azure resource manager.

While attempting to create run this script I am getting the error message. " The term 'Add-AzureRmVpnClientRootCertificate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

I am currently running Azure Powershell version 1.0.1 and this reference, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt653593.aspx, indicates that it should be available in version 1.0.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need at least Azure PowerShell 1.0.4 to get this cmdlet. If you look at the GitHub source for this cmdlet at https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/master/src/ResourceManager/Network/Commands.Network/VirtualNetworkGateway/AddAzureVpnClientRootCertificateCommand.cs, it looks like it was added with the commit for 1.0.4: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/commit/09b5f57ff798ca90aeb84e73fbd88f406d7edd7c.